# Trouble with WRITE statement and line continuations in Fortran

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, abaqus

I am currently trying to figure out the problem with a line continuation in Fortran, and I'm new to the language. I am writing this for use with the software package ABAQUS, where all of the compilation is done using `ifort`. I believe the compilation is set to be compatible with Fortran 90. I have tried all of the below configurations for a line continuation in the middle of a `WRITE` statement:

---

```
        FILENAME = TRIM(KMC_DATADIR) // '/elementInfo.txt'
        OPEN(1001, FILE=FILENAME, STATUS="REPLACE", ACTION="WRITE")     

        FS = '(I5,I5,I5,F12.10)'

        DO K1=1,KMC_NUMELEM
            WRITE(1001,FS) KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%IDNUM, KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%MATID,
     &      KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%TRANSFORMED, KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%ORIENT%RMAT(1,1)
        END DO

        CLOSE(1001)
```

---

```
        FILENAME = TRIM(KMC_DATADIR) // '/elementInfo.txt'
        OPEN(1001, FILE=FILENAME, STATUS="REPLACE", ACTION="WRITE")     

        FS = '(I5,I5,I5,F12.10)'

        DO K1=1,KMC_NUMELEM
            WRITE(1001,FS) KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%IDNUM, KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%MATID, &
            KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%TRANSFORMED, KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%ORIENT%RMAT(1,1)
        END DO

        CLOSE(1001)
```

---

```
        FILENAME = TRIM(KMC_DATADIR) // '/elementInfo.txt'
        OPEN(1001, FILE=FILENAME, STATUS="REPLACE", ACTION="WRITE")     

        FS = '(I5,I5,I5,F12.10)'

        DO K1=1,KMC_NUMELEM
            WRITE(1001,FS) KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%IDNUM, KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%MATID, &
     &      KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%TRANSFORMED, KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%ORIENT%RMAT(1,1)
        END DO

        CLOSE(1001)
```

---

The compiler error I keep getting is this:

TRIPTrans.f(55): error #5082: Syntax error, found '&' when expecting one of: (     ...

```
       WRITE(1001,FS) KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%IDNUM,KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%MATID, &
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

Am I allowed to split a write statement onto multiple lines?

Comment: Is this compiled as fixed-form source?  If it is, how did the first one fail?

Comment: *" I believe the compilation is set to be compatible with fortran 90."* What does that mean? How set? How do you compile it?

Comment: The compilation is done by ifort, and the compilation environment is controlled by the ABAQUS software. I set the compilation flags in an abaqus environment file. Here are the flags I'm using:  compile_fortran = (fortCmd + " -g -c -O0 -fPIC -r8 -save -mP2OPT_hpo_vec_divbyzero=F " +
                  "-extend_source -w90 -w95 -WB -I%I -shared-intel -mcmodel medium")

Comment: I recommend you replace "-extend_source" with "-free" in the .env file, and then you just end each continued line with `&`. Alternatively, put the compiler directive `!DIR$ FREEFORM` at the beginning of your subroutine. Then you have the advantage of writing in free-form, but it won't mess with the environment anyone else might be expecting and their old fixed-form programs will still compile!

Comment: Your first form is correct for fixed form, assuming the ampersand is in column 6.  *except* you appear to be pushing too long even with the continuation.   ( If you work in fixed form you really need an editor that understands the line structure. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is *not* compatible with the `-extend_source` Intel Fortran compiler option.

What the option does is that it extends the length of the line from 72 to 132 characters for fixed form sources. That might be convenient, *however*, many codes use the space after column 72 to store comments.

Indeed, your `&` in

```
WRITE(1001,FS) KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%IDNUM,KMC_ELEMENTS(K1)%MATID, &
```

is supposed to be a comment, invisible to the compiler. It is usually done to create files which are compatible with fixed and free form at the same time. But it is not invisible, due to `-extend source`.

If you need the `-extend source` option, you can only use the `&` in the 6th column on the new line. You cannot use the additional one on the previous line.

---

If, on the other hand, the code is supposed to be *free-form*, (you haven't told us!), then you must instruct the compiler by using the `-free` option.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody happens across this question, my problem was a combination of the answer posted above as well as the nature of the white space in my source code. The continuation character needs to be in the 6th column, and something about my setup (compilation settings?) caused it to not recognize a 'tab' as multiple columns. I had to explicitly space over (using the spacebar) 5 times then place the continuation character. A combination of tab and spaces would not compile correctly.

Given my lack of experience with FORTRAN, I'm not sure if that is a common problem or not.

Comment: Yes, you should not use tabs in Fortran! Unfortunately, this problem cannot be seen from the question.